# Gesture recogniser not working when other view is on top of the google maps

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, uigesturerecognizer

I am trying to add swipe gesture recognizer for a sidebar. I have created  a side bar which is working fine and I can open/close it using a bar button. View is sliding out of left side and is placed on top of the google maps view.

It would be only logical if user would be able to sfipe to the left to close side bar, but unfortunately it is not working.

```
@IBOutlet weak var sideMenuView: UIView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
        mapView.delegate = self

        self.locationManager.delegate = self
        self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

        setUpSideMenuWidth()


        let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swipeAction))
        swipeLeft.direction = .left
        self.sideMenuView.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)
    }

func setUpSideMenuWidth() {

    self.mapView.bringSubviewToFront(self.sideMenuView)

    sideMenuWidth = screenSize.width * 0.7
    self.widthSideMenuConstraint.constant = sideMenuWidth
    self.leadingConstraint.constant = -sideMenuWidth
    self.sideMenuView.layoutIfNeeded()
}

@objc func swipeAction(swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

   menuViewAction()
}

func menuViewAction() {

    if (menuShowing) {
        self.leadingConstraint.constant = -sideMenuWidth

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    } else {
        self.leadingConstraint.constant = 0

        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }

    menuShowing = !menuShowing
}
```

I somehow feel that it is related that my side menu is a subview of mapsView. Have everyone faced such problem because when I use simply a bar button it opens and closes perfectly but swipe is not working by some kind of reason. I have also tried to add gesture view storyboard but without luck.

Comment: If you bringToFron your mapView like this `self.mapView.bringSubviewToFront(self.sideMenuView)` it's normal that you won't be able to detect other gestures, because the view on top is mapView.

Comment: Where are you adding the sideMenuView to the stack? is it placed inside the mapView? it should be placed on top of the mapView, not inside. Check the stack of views with the "Debug View Hierarchy" button in Xcode

Comment: I have checked it and it is placed on the top of mapView in view hierarchy.